# Scheduling a jar file in Quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am able to schedule java files using quartz scheduler. Is scheduling jar files is possible using quartz scheduler?

Comment: How does the jar get executed?

Comment: I don't understand what "scheduling jar files" means? Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: If you want, I can point you to our *free* product that we call QuartzDesk Executor that allows you to execute arbitrary scripts/commands with Quartz scheduler - either locally or remotely (via SSH). I think you would be able to use it if you either create a simple shell script to wrap the execution of your jar (e.g. java -cp foo.jar), or you can extend the QE app and implement a custom Quartz job that loads your JAR and executes one of its main classes. QE sources are available.

Comment: Hi Lathy, Consider the following example.. http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/ . Here the quartz job file is HelloJob.java which is scheduled to run every 30 seconds. Similarly I have a HelloJob.jar which should run every 30 seconds.